# where to get information about isSigner and isWritable from the transaction data?

Tags: web3.js, spl-token, token, spl-token-program, transaction-instructions

in the package @solana/web3.js there is such type AccountMeta

```
/**
 * Account metadata used to define instructions
 */
type AccountMeta = {
    /** An account's public key */
    pubkey: PublicKey;
    /** True if an instruction requires a transaction signature matching `pubkey` */
    isSigner: boolean;
    /** True if the `pubkey` can be loaded as a read-write account. */
    isWritable: boolean;
};
```

I use this type to decode the data. I get the data from transactions. After poking around in this data, I can't find any information about **isSigner** and **isWritable**. Where to get them?

raw data looks like this

```
{
  blockTime: 1705557623,
  indexWithinBlock: 248,
  meta: {
    err: null,
    fee: 6400,
    innerInstructions: [],
    loadedAddresses: { readonly: [], writable: [] },
    logMessages:[],
    postBalances: [],
    postTokenBalances: [],
    preBalances:[],
    preTokenBalances: [],
    rewards: []
  },
  slot: 242508962,
  transaction: {
    message: {
      accountKeys: [Array],
      addressTableLookups: null,
      header: [Object],
      instructions: [Array],
      recentBlockhash: ''
    },
    signatures:''
   ]
  },
  version: 'legacy'
}
```

I'm taking the data from all the keys.

```
tx.transaction.message.accountKeys => [
  '9iGipTrLnL8qWWUPoBBxiktcdfDPUJRKAv2xeCG1K7UU',
  '5jjxRiSnBPTE8WDCBnGRw4n9zXcpgXYowyGVN2JVuQ3E',
  '73p6jUhJ1iRB2Prc5qEfserpFprFs5QhwqYfNzjXeATQ',
  'ComputeBudget111111111111111111111111111111',
  '11111111111111111111111111111111',
  'TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA',
  'So11111111111111111111111111111111111111112',
  '675kPX9MHTjS2zt1qfr1NYHuzeLXfQM9H24wFSUt1Mp8'
]
```

taking instructions

```
tx.transaction.message.instructions => { accounts: [ 1, 6, 0, 19 ], data: '2', programIdIndex: 5 }
```

the numbers in accounts `accounts: [ 1, 6, 0, 19 ]` are indices from the AccountsKeys array?
How to work with them? Where do they refer to?
because I get `Error TokenInvalidInstructionKeysError when decoding.`

decode with decodeInstruction from @solana/spl-token

For the `decodeInstruction` function from @solana/spl-token you need to provide an array of keys. which will have values matching the `AccountMeta` type. But I did not find information about isSigner and isWritable in the transaction data. Where to get them?

So, two questions. Where to get information about isSigner and isWritable? from the raw data I showed you above. I want to provide this information to the decodeInstruction function

second question, what do these numbers in the accounts field indicate?
I don't think they are indexes, because index number 19, from `accounts: [1, 6, 0, 19]` would be undefined, since `accountKeys` doesn't have that many keys.

if they are indices, it means that there are missing keys in the `accountKeys` data array. Is this even possible?

**update.**

Thanks for your comments, it helped me. i want to make sure i understand the situation correctly. Since my headers are different. Could you please give me an example based on this data.

```
accountKeys: [
  'DG5Ba67Ys5U5JcrMjcE3urmorYErguhuViLg7CuZy4Nq',
  'EUUpDKRbWWFtA8SrKgiEMBvvsG3YST7bWHo4nJVimV2Q',
  'E6TsJB737Mm85VaJtQJSoMkZS619UU6qLLUx3qDSevZx',
  '6vLZ6Kz46rRsC9EsRwYP1C2Cqwfq4jA9SMjVzK1MmoQ5',
  '9DCxsMizn3H1hprZ7xWe6LDzeUeZBksYFpBWBtSf1PQX',
  '6Hqq4Zxdqj6HzLS11y5vEnCd2qxT1gQtG4NjCJ3D8CGu',
  'EP6kxz5emawLyZ1MrwZsejcZ3YjvLwxJheriUwAQyJJV',
  'Eo1HHS36tkXAmWtr9a6vWAqL9WnZGiFzmCwd6r1Ayaqv',
  'HX9RH6AXiwjZbrzp2aaBw7vVTqJL6qP4XAgxH9bTP9rK',
  'A5aZrtA7MQZ1W31Dew2rEw2gBboVPR7XZeQ24QaGpzzW',
  '5BHWbF5cbAPb6CgrqNoFHme1a7QDqcV1NGqbpyTe7ywz',
  '3GAjr3LTaP4VAYv1eiSTFoGYkrmGwmaEebdbya8K38Qq',
  '4NFdKk5up2xAmQKRUwrcFPKp77tw8HXRxKPh52HgRat3',
  'B7fmLgen6Rniq8EBgPrT4HSzPrfe4JTMSJxALuRNB31B',
  'K1LRSA1DSoKBtC5DkcvnermRQ62YxogWSCZZPWQrdG5',
  'ComputeBudget111111111111111111111111111111',
  '11111111111111111111111111111111',
  'TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA',
  'So11111111111111111111111111111111111111112',
  '675kPX9MHTjS2zt1qfr1NYHuzeLXfQM9H24wFSUt1Mp8',
  '5Q544fKrFoe6tsEbD7S8EmxGTJYAKtTVhAW5Q5pge4j1',
  '2ws3teGMs2Z9PhVLZjPnfPxU7zFdT7jTSojXRVe1Ctjs'
]

headers: {
  numReadonlySignedAccounts: 0,
  numReadonlyUnsignedAccounts: 7,
  numRequiredSignatures: 1
} 

insturction: { accounts: [ 1, 18, 0, 22 ], data: '2', programIdIndex: 17 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The information about `isSigner` and `isWritable` comes from the `header` field of the transaction. It contains this data:

```
numReadonlyUnsignedAccounts: number;
numReadonlySignedAccounts: number;
numRequiredSignatures: number;
```

The accounts are ordered, with writable signers first, then read-only signers, then writable accounts, then read-only. I'll ignore address table lookups for now, but they go after all these.

So, let's say `numRequiredSignatures` was 2. That would mean that the first two accounts, `9iGipTrLnL8qWWUPoBBxiktcdfDPUJRKAv2xeCG1K7UU` and `5jjxRiSnBPTE8WDCBnGRw4n9zXcpgXYowyGVN2JVuQ3E` are signers. All other accounts are not.

Now let's say `numReadonlySignedAccounts` was 1. That would mean that the first account, `9iGipTrLnL8qWWUPoBBxiktcdfDPUJRKAv2xeCG1K7UU` is writable, and the second account, `5jjxRiSnBPTE8WDCBnGRw4n9zXcpgXYowyGVN2JVuQ3E` is not.

Now we know the `isSigner` and `isWritable` status of our 2 signer accounts. We know the other 6 accounts are not signers, but not which of them are writable.

Now let's say `numReadonlyUnsignedAccounts` is 4. Notice this is the last of our categories, not signer and read-only. This would mean that the last 4 accounts are not writable: from `11111111111111111111111111111111` to the last account. And that means that our 3rd and 4th account, `73p6jUhJ1iRB2Prc5qEfserpFprFs5QhwqYfNzjXeATQ` and `ComputeBudget111111111111111111111111111111` are writable.

So basically you can use the header information and the order of the account to derive `isSigner` and `isWritable` for every account.

You can see example code that does this here: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-web3.js/blob/ca243cbe943d31ea7f587ca6890d7c67d5493fa2/packages/transactions/src/decompile-transaction.ts#L20 This is part of the new/experimental web3js so the data structures (and field names) are different, but hopefully it's quite legible!

--

Using the numbers in your updated question, you have:

- `numRequiredSignatures` is 1, so only the first account, `DG5Ba67Ys5U5JcrMjcE3urmorYErguhuViLg7CuZy4Nq` is a signer. All others are not
- `numReadonlySignedAccounts` is 0, so that signer is writable.
- `numReadonlyUnsignedAccounts` is 7, so the last 7 accounts are read-only (starting with `ComputeBudget111111111111111111111111111111` to the end of the array), all other non-signer accounts are writable.

--

On the second part of your question, you're correct that those numbers are indices into the `accountKeys` array. Given that your transaction version is `legacy` you can't have any address lookup tables, which would usually be the explanation for indices that are greater than the length of that array. You have 22 account keys, so I'm not sure where index 22 is coming from, that'd be undefined. Can you give a link to this transaction on an explorer so I can take a look?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. very helpful. only my headers are different. Do they have the same working principle? Are there any peculiarities?

my headers: =>

  numReadonlySignedAccounts: 0,
  numReadonlyUnsignedAccounts: 7,
  numRequiredSignatures: 1

Comment: I've edited the answer to use those field names, they have the same meaning just slightly reworded. And added the explanation using those numbers. I noticed you updated `accountKeys` and it now has 22 accounts - so index 19 makes sense now. But then you added an instruction with `22` so I'm still stumped on that! Can you link to the transaction on an explorer?

Comment: I apologize for not being precise enough. I'm not a native English speaker, so this data is from different transactions that come to me. I didn't save their signatures. But you've helped me a lot. I think I've solved my problem. Thank you.

Comment: I think I will ask a separate question about the fact that I have different number of keys and different number of indexes, but first I will gather enough information.